# How to uninstall package using puppet

Tags: puppet

I have installed mysql in a client node using Puppet. Now I want to uninstall it in the client node. I tried the following configuration in site.pp:

```
  package { '::mysql::server':
    ensure => 'purged'
  }
```

This did not work. Can someone show me how to uninstall mysql (or any package for that matter)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That syntax is wrong. `::mysql::server` is either referencing a puppet class or defined type. You only need to specify the package name to the package type.

```
 package { 'mysql_package_name':
   ensure => absent
 }
```

Replacing `mysql_package_name` with the name of the package for the distro you are using.